# Error with Receiver Export on API 34: "One of RECEIVER_EXPORTED or RECEIVER_NOT_EXPORTED Should be Specified"

Tags: java, android, kotlin, gradle, google-play-core

I am developing an Android application and encountered the following error message:

One of RECEIVER_EXPORTED or RECEIVER_NOT_EXPORTED should be specified when a receiver isn't being registered exclusively for system broadcasts.

This error occurred when I was using com.google.android.play:core:1.10.3. I suspect it's related to how broadcast receivers are registered or managed in the app. Since I use this libraries in app update functions, I can not remove it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With new google updates, they extract in app update from core library. You can remove this

```
implementation 'com.google.android.play:core:1.10.3'
```

And add this

```
implementation 'com.google.android.play:app-update:2.1.0'
```

After making this change, sync your project with the updated Gradle files. This should resolve the error related to the RECEIVER_EXPORTED or RECEIVER_NOT_EXPORTED specification in API 34.

Thanks for @pakman suggestion, you can see the migration details on this official source. here: https://developer.android.com/guide/playcore/in-app-updates/kotlin-java

Comment: You need to do a few more things. A better link is this: https://developer.android.com/guide/playcore#playcore-migration

Comment: Can you explain why is that so @pakman that on updating the libarries we no longer need to include  RECEIVER_EXPORTED or RECEIVER_NOT_EXPORTED flags in the reciever since it was made mandatory in android 14?

Answer (score 0):

The answer given by @burhanyaprak is correct, i was facing the same issue right now, but the solution is not complete, what actually happened is

`implementation 'com.google.android.play:core:1.10.3'`

is indeed an old library, and according to official docs, this particular library is divided into four seperate library which are

*Play Asset Delivery Library*

*Play Feature Delivery Library*

*Play In-App Reviews Library*

*Play In-App Updates Library*

All the integration step is [Mentioned here](https://developer.android.com/guide/playcore) from Common migration steps

and you will be good to go.